# Can you view PHP script code straight from the web server

Tags: php

I am a complete PHP novice and I am just trying to write a simple web form and script that checks to see if the input matches a specific string. I have got that working no problem and just want to know if there is some way for the web form user to parse the script code and see what I am comparing to, therefore revealing the secret message to them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the php executes, no.  if you see the php code, yes

Comment: PHP code is executed by the server before it even gets to the client. What the user sees is what the PHP script outputs.

Comment: As far as I know, PHP is parsed *server-side*, and after that, the output is HTML code. So the answer is "no" (if the script runs correctly)

Answer (score 2):

If there is a missconfiguration with your apache server, then it is a possibility. But other than that, PHP is server-sided scripting and will remain visible to only the server/FTP users.